# MySQL Return multiple rows if aggregated value is more than 1

Tags: mysql

Table has aggregated values but i need to return multiple rows if the value is greater than one.

Here is how the table looks now:

```
date  description   amount

1/1/2015   alpha    3

1/1/2015    beta    1
```

Here is how i need it to return:

```
date    description amount

1/1/2015    alpha   1

1/1/2015    alpha   1

1/1/2015    alpha   1

1/1/2015    beta    1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to do this by constructing a query in a stored proc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how that query would be constructed?

Comment: I'll see if I have time later today. But the basic idea would be to construct a string containing the necessary number of `UNION`s by iterating through the rows and looping on `amount`, then using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to run the final query.

By the way, is there any reason to have the `amount` column in the final result set?

Comment: Actually, using Gordon's solution, you wouldn't even have to iterate over the rows to create the `UNION`s; you rely on the `JOIN` to do that, and just loop until `MAX(amount)`.

Comment: Interesting, i really appreciate you taking a look. I'm pulling aggregated event data on a minute level aggregate then uploading into an antiquated system that does not function correctly with aggregated data. It requires these records to be inserted as individual events. So if there are 3 events in a single minute or day, it requires 3 individual records but it does still require a value for amount = 1. If inserting the "1" is a show stopper, then i can always create the output table and then add an update statement that inserts the 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need a table of numbers.  Something like this works for up to 3 and can be easily extended:

```
select t.date, t.description, 1 as amount
from table t join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
     on n.n <= t.amount;
```

EDIT:

If you have enough rows in the table for the larger amounts, you can do:

```
select t.date, t.description, 1 as amount
from table t join
     (select @rn := @rn + 1 as n
      from table cross join (select @rn := 0) vars
     ) n
     on n.n <= t.amount;
```

Comment: Thanks. When running this query, it's multiplying records even if the amount is already = 1. Also, the amount can range significantly, up into the thousands. Is there an alternative that is not limited to the incremental unions in your code?

Comment: I was able to correct multiplying records when the amount already =1 by switching "<=" to ">=". However, I'm still not sure how to get around scenarios where the value for amount can be significantly higher than 3 (other than continuing to type out the unions for each incremental value).

Comment: For the last edit, i'm getting a syntax error near '@rn := 0) vars
     ) n......

Comment: You don't need the `JOIN` in there; just update the `SELECT` to `@rn := IFNULL(@rn, 0) + 1`.

Comment: Here is the query i am running and it's coming back with 0 results. What have i messed up? 
select t.date, t.description, 1 as amount
from table t join
     (select @rn := IFNULL(@rn, 0) + 1 as n
      from table
     ) n
     on n.n <= t.amount;

Comment: @jrod2020, it works for me. But keep in mind, it'll only work if the number of rows in `table` is not less than the maximum `amount` value. (You can always point the subquery to another table if you have a larger one.)

Comment: In this particular instance, the row count is roughly 5k and the maximum value for amount is 13. However, it is still coming back with 0 results. I'll keep playing with it and see if i can get it working. Thank you both for the help, i really do appreciate it. I feel it's closer than it was before posting the question.

Comment: I was able to get this working when going back to including the cross join in the subquery. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly.

select t.date, t.description, 1 as amount
from table t join
     (select @rn := @rn + 1 as n
      from table cross join (select @rn := 0) vars
     ) n
     on n.n <= t.amount;